# Silverlight Chart Question

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts

I haven't enough rep points to post an image yet but given a Silverlight 4 chart example using ColumnSeries, how can I make each of the sub columns within a single column that are currently stacked up on top of each other sit side by side?

e.g Column NVQ2 shows value columns for 5 different locations, Column NVQ3 shows value columns for 5 different locations

I need the locations to sit side by side and not be stacked on top of each other.

Code for the graph:

```
foreach (ER_Location theLocation in UserSelections.TheDataSet.ER_Locations)
                    {
                        ER_Year myYear = (ER_Year)SeriesSelection.SelectedItem;
                        ColumnSeries newSeries = new ColumnSeries();
                        newSeries.ItemsSource = UserSelections.GetDataRowsByYearAndLocation(theLocation.Location_ID, (int)myYear.Year);
                        newSeries.IndependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Variable_ID");
                        newSeries.DependentValueBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("Value");
                        newSeries.Title = theLocation.Name;
                        newSeries.IsSelectionEnabled = true;
                        MainChart.Series.Add(newSeries);
                    }
```

**Update:**

This is how the chart is rendering at present:
[image]

Comment: Are you using the term "Stacked" in the usual sense when refering to charts?  Normally multiple column series in a chart would place each column for a specific IndependentValue side-by-side.  You'd need to using a StackedColumnSeries to get them to stack.

Comment: If I can boost up my Rep to 10 tonight I'll post a pic tomorrow which explains it visually! I can't post a pic at the minute.

Comment: Added in how it is currently rendering, maybe this gives a better indication of the problem. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your code has the following `using` statement:-

```
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Compatible
```

There are actually two different types with the name `ColumnSeries`.  One is in the above namespace and it derives from `StackedColumnSeries`.

However the original non-stacked `ColumnSeries` exists in the main Charting namespace.  This type will place each column side-by-side.  Hence I suspect all you need to do is eliminate the extra `.Compatible` from your `using`:-

```
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

Comment: Many thanks for this Anthony, that's works now in showing the bars side by side. However all the bars are now showing in the same colour whereas before they appeared in different colours? Is there anything obvious I should be doing?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a class with the color property.

Example,

```
public class MyColor
{
    public Brush ChartColor { get; set; }
}
```

then create a list of your favorite colors like

```
List<MyColor> colorList = new List<MyColor>
{
    new MyColor
      { ChartColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)},
    new MyColor
      { ChartColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) },
    ...
    ...
}
```

From Xaml, bind the background color of the datapoint to ChartColor